# TypeError with undefined amount of parameters

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm building a Discord Bot and I want to call the the first play function from class 1, that you can see below, from another class. I made another function for that down below, but when I run it, I get a TypeError:

> TypeError: play() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

I think it gives me an error because I'm giving the function an undefined amount of parameters because it worked with a defined amount. Thanks for helping me already!

```
class1:
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

class2:
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

    instance = class1()

    await instance.play(instance, ctx, url) #place where the error occurs
```

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined amount of parameters"? You seem to be confusing `*, url` with `*url`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the python documentation:

```
# The second syntactical change is to allow the argument name to be omitted for a varargs argument. 
# The meaning of this is to allow for keyword-only arguments for functions that would not otherwise take a varargs argument:

def compare(a, b, *, key=None):
    ...
```

When you use `(args1, args2, ... argsn, *, more_args)` that means that args1..n are positional while `more_args` can only be passed as a keyword argument with the form `more_args=something`

Therefore you must do something like this:

```
await instance.play(instance, ctx, url=url)
```